# Load google-services.json from local file system

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The `google-services.json` file used by the [Firebase Android plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) is usually put in the app's module folder.

What I do want to do instead is put this file somewhere on the filesystem completely outside the project folder and let gradle / the Firebase plugin read it from there.

I thought about putting it's location in the `local.properties` and somehow 'tell' the Firebase plugin to get the location of the `google-services.json` from there. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [offical documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file), the `google-services.json` file is generally placed in the `app/ directory` (at the root of the Android Studio app module). As of version 2.2.0 the plugin supports build type and product flavor specific JSON files. All of the following directory structures are valid:

```
// dogfood and release are build types.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
    ...
```

> Note: Providing a google-services.json file in the release directory allows you to maintain a separate Firebase project for your production APKs.
>   When product flavors are in use these more complicated directory structures are also valid.

```
// free and paid are product flavors.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/paid/google-services.json
    src/release/free/google-services.json
    ...
```

As a conclusion, you cannot add `google-services.json` file outside your project.

Hope it helps.